# Problems retrieving separate Document in Map-Function

Tags: javascript, map-function

I've written a little function to get results based on two search terms a user can make. The terms are: `owner & path` of a folder.

The map function down below works so far that it gives me back the right folder when a user looks for `bob` & `holiday`. 
Unfortunately the `elfe if` part doesn't work, where I want to retrieve the files document. If I separate both `if`'s everything works. Why not in combination? :-)

**Map-Function:**

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'folder') {
      emit([doc.owner, doc.path], null);
    } else if (doc.files) {    
    for (var i in doc.files) {
          emit(doc.owner, {_id: doc.files[i]});
      } 
  }
}
```

**Documents:**

```
// Folder
{
  "_id": "folder.abc",
  "name": "Holiday",
  "type": "folder",
  "owner": "bob",
  "path": "\\holiday",
  "files": [
    "file.123"
    ]
}

// Files
{
  "_id": "file.123",
  "name": "Hawaii.jpg",
  "type": "file",
}
```

**Search Query:**

`[Snip]?key=["bob","\\holiday"]&include_docs=true`

**Result:**

```
{
    "total_rows":4,
    "offset":2,
    "rows":[
        {
            "id":"folder.abc",
            "key":[
                "bob",
                "\\holiday"
            ],
            "value":null,
            "doc":{
                "_id":"folder.abc",
                "name":"Holiday",
                "type":"folder",
                "owner":"bob",
                "path":"\\holiday",
                "files":[
                    "file.123"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately the elfe if part doesn't work, where I want to retrieve the files document. If I separate both if's everything works. Why not in combination? :-)

This doesn't work because JavaScript doesn't have an `elseif` keyword. Using `else if` is equivalent to:

```
if (doc.type === 'folder') {
    ...
} else {
    if (doc.files) {
        ...
    }
}
```

see: [MDN if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)